# How to make a program open how the user left it

Tags: java

So im making a program fully text based. Using JOptionPane only and i was wondering. Can the user open the program and continue his save?

Comment: You might need somewhere to save the data like a database or text file. Then when the program starts, you can populate the page.

Comment: Your question is "is it possible". The answer is "yes".

Comment: 1) Persist the state of the program somewhere when exiting.  2) Read the persisted state when starting the program.  3) Modify the state of the program to match the persisted state.  It's a fairly broad response, I realize.  But it's a fairly broad question.

Comment: What if the program relies on time? What if its exit state contains data from the system where it executes and that data changes between exit and restart - what was valid then need not be valid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, to create a save file on exit. So when the program starts up it looks for a saved file, if there is one available then load it up and the user can continue.

Comment: Why was this down voted? This would be the easiest solution given the unkown complexity of the app.

Comment: The only reason I can think is to dissuade people from answering low quality questions.